# Entity framework(Code first) - & ASP.net Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am currently trying to build a new application using EF6 Code First, I manage to create the database based on my models no problem.

Now what I want to do is use asp.net membership features. So I will have to have the database schema inside my database.

How can I do this?

There is information around the internet on using the simplemembershipprovider with EF, but it is very confusing.

Just so you have an idea of what I have done so far...(below)

So what is the best way to use membership with EF?

```
namespace AsoRock.Data.DTOs
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string HomeNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string LastUsed { get; set; }
        public bool isDefault { get; set; }
    }


    public class AsoRockContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
       // public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithMany().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("OrderId").MapRightKey("ProductId").ToTable("OrderdProducts");
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: which version asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC 5 then you can change your 
    public class AsoRockContext : DbContext

to be

```
public class AsoRockContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Then create your ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{   //You can add extra properties in if you want
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //Or add a link to your customer table
    public Customer CustomerDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me some more information. I currently only have one project in my solution (AsoRock.Data) <br/>This is where I am putting all the EF code. (Code First) So if I create a MVC5 Project (AsoRock.Web) are you saying that I would be calling AsoRockContext inside in AsoRock.Data

Comment: Can you give me some more information. I currently only have one project in my solution (AsoRock.Data) This is where I am putting all the EF code. (Code First) So if I create a MVC5 Project (AsoRock.Web) are you saying that I would be calling AsoRockContext inside in AsoRock.Data and how does that effect the automatic creation of the database when I update the model? @ASG

Comment: You could put your Context (and DbSets) in your MVC Project then add reference to your AsoRock.Data project

Comment: When you said put the Context and Dbsets in the MVC project I assume you mean all the code that creates the database...right? Well then if I did that I wouldn't need a .data project.?

Comment: Depends on the scale of the project. If you are going to reuse your data classes elsewhere then keep it. As long as your MVC Poject references it you can create your Context and DbSets using any other projects

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net MVC 4+ comes with asp.net membership provider.
So you context name  is `TestConnection` then

in the AccountModel in Model Directory, Change the `defaultConnection` to `TestConnection`
like this, then it will create membership table in your DB.

```
 public UsersContext()
            : base("TestConnection")
        {
        }
```

to know more about how it is achieve see the code, see the AccountController file and find the following in top
     [InitializeSimpleMembership]
     public class AccountController : Controller

Inspect the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` attribute to learn how it is implemented.